# Replace specific color pixels in an image

Tags: c#, image

I have few images captured via a webcam in C#. I want to do some processing on these images. I want to delete pixels from images that are not in black color.

Please tell me how can I delete pixels or areas that are not in black color and replace that with white color.

Example:

[image]

And I want to convert it like:

[image]

Comment: but the border is black too, how are you going to separate *semantics* of black entites on image ?. I would suggest to look on: http://opencv.org/ and relative .net wrappers availble on internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to go through every pixels and verify whether or not it is in the 'accepted' range of colors.

For instance:

```
var YourImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("LicensePlate.png");

for (var x = 0; x < YourImage.Width; x++)
   for (var y = 0; y < YourImage.Height; y++) {
       var pixel = YourImage.GetPixel(x, y);
       if (pixel.r > 200 && pixel.g > 200 && pixel.b > 200)
                YourImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
   }
```

The above code will replace the area that is not black with a white pixel.

Comment: This would be slooooooow. The GetPixel/SetPixel methods are really slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ***[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)*** (OpenCV in .NET), specially see [License Plate Recognition in CSharp](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp) example.

Answer (score -1):

EmguCV wraper for OpenCV is a good start and the license plate should get you through most of the cases. If you want something more robust (change in illumination) I would recommend you to add wolf's binarization. I don't know if it was implemented in EmguCV but there is c++ code available at http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/binarize/
which would be easy to adapt to c# using EmguCV.